# Read path from file and check if file exists in a specified path

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to read a PATH from a text file and check whether the file exists in the PATH specified in the "input.txt" file. Though the file is present in the specified location. The loop continues to run.Please help

Below is my VBScript

```
Set oReadObj  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oRead = oReadObj.OpenTextFile("C:\input.txt", 1)
loc = oRead.ReadAll()

Do Until oReadObj.FileExists(loc) 
wscript.sleep 5000    
Loop

msgbox "file found"
```

Answer (score 0):

.ReadAll() may include a EOL from the file, which surely isn't part of the path; use .ReadLine(), as you just want to get **one** path.

**On second thought:**

There may be other junk (spaces, BOM, ...) in your file. Did you try something like

```
WScript.Echo ">" & loc & "<"
```

to check for those or typos?

**Reboot:**

Based your comments:

> If I specify the "path(location of installer)" instead of variable
>   "loc", I am getting expected result
>
> This is the content of my " input.txt" file
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Storage_Manager_Server-windows-x86_64-6.0.0.ex‌​e"

we can

1. rule out permission problems (usual suspects if "Administrator" pops up)
2. conclude that `loc` - i.e. the file's content - is to blame

If we are sure that EOL's, blanks, typos are **not** the cause of .FileExists' failure, then the most likely hypothesis is: **The file contains the "** (quoted path), which is good for the shell, but fatal for FileSystemObject methods.

Comment: This is the content of my " input.txt" file "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Storage_Manager_Server-windows-x86_64-6.0.0.exe". I don't see any spaces or blanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a loop to check if the file exists (if you have the full path of it), here is the code you need.

```
Set oReadObj  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oRead = oReadObj.OpenTextFile("C:\input.txt", 1)
loc = oRead.ReadAll()

If oReadObj.FileExists(loc) Then msgbox "file found" else msgbox "file not found"
```

Comment: I need to install the software in the location present in my "input.text" file. That is the reason I am using the loop. The loop should continue to run until the file is found in the specified location. The Problem I am facing here is, though the file is present in the mentioned location, the loop continues to run

Comment: Note: If I specify the "path(location of installer)" instead of variable "loc", I am getting expected result.